# Getting and manipulating product ID

Tags: jquery

I want to clarify what would be a proper way to getting and manipulating product ID. Here is my attempt:

HTML:

```
<div data-product-id="100"></div>
```

Script:

```
var pid = $(this).attr('data-product-id');
$('#product_' + pid).css('display', 'none');
```

Is there a better way that `$('#product_' + pid)`?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can use is not using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to access data attributes, otherwise using product id number and concatenating it with for prefix like product_ is fine if you do not have a lot of elements otherwise you can use p_ to save some bytes.

To see the difference between data() and attribute you can read this [**article**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr).

```
var pid = $(this).data('product-id');
$('#product_' + pid).css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: I see my title was misleading. Changed that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do it like:

```
$('#product_id').hide();
```

but if you insists:

```
$('#product_' + $(this).data('product-id')).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#product_' + $(this).data('product-id')).css('display', 'none');;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only real problem with your code is that it wouldn't work for any id. For example it wouldn't work if you have dots or parenthesis inside your data attribute.

In that case, you would have to do

```
$(document.getElementById('product_' + $(this).data('product-id')))
    .css('display', 'none');
```

If you know what ID you have, and that they're not fancy, then your code is mostly fine.

Comment: Good point. My product id is just a number so it should be fine.

Comment: Well, then, apart the very minor `data` thing, there isn't much to say about your code.